# SQL Query Result Problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, casting

I have Two SQL Query Both Return

> select round(convert(float,'24367.723'),2)
>
> Result:24367.72

Second:

> select convert(varchar(20),round(convert(float,'24367.723'),2))
>
> > Result:24367.7

Why the Second Query Return exclude the last digit after converting to varchar

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By not specifying a style parameter to the convert function you get the default style (0).

i.e. it is equivalent to doing

```
select convert(varchar(20),round(convert(float,'24367.723'),2), 0)
```

The [default style for converting from float to varchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) displays a maximum of 6 digits.

Answer (score 0):

When working with a float the STR() function usually gives better results according to MSDN as you've more control.

E.g.

```
select str(convert(float,'24367.723'),8, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use floats, use exact numberics. Something like this

```
   convert(varchar(20), convert(numeric(20,2), '24367.72'))
```